# If $n$ is odd, then there are exactly two conjugacy classes of n-cycles in $A_n$ each of which contains $(n - 1)!/2$ elements.

Tags: group-theory

My approach:

Define $X = \{\alpha \in A_n \ | \ \alpha \  \textrm{is an n-cycle}\}$ and the group action $G: A_n \to S_X: g \mapsto gxg^{-1}$. Then for an $\alpha$ the stabilizer group is $\{\beta \ | \ \beta \textrm{ is an n cycle or the identity} \}$ (I'm stuck on proving this is the entire stabiliser group), and the orbit of $\alpha$ is the conjugacy class of $\alpha$ itself, so by the orbit-stabilzer theorem the size of the conjugacy class is equal to the size of the quotient group of $G$ and the stabiliser which would be $n!/2/n = (n - 1)!/2$.

Because there are $(n - 1)!$ $n$-cycles there must be exactly 2 conjugacy classes. So now the only part left is proving that their size must be $(n - 1)!/2$ which is also why this differs from the question linked as duplicate.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How many $n$-cycles are there altogether?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $(n - 1)!$ because you can order $n$ elements in $n!$ ways, and you can write a single permutation in $n$ ways because it is cyclic, so you have to divide by $n$.

Comment: So, there are $(n-1)!$ $n$-cycles. In each conjugacy class there are $(n-1)!/2$ elements. So, how many conjugacy classes must there be?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown 2, so the problem simplifies to proving that the stabilizer group consists out of only n cycles and the identity. Thanks, that was easier than I expected!